# Unity emission isn't updating when I change the material

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering

Emission works in my game so far ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTJea.png)).
I am trying to make my car blink a color every 1-5 seconds, for some reason when I change my material to the emissive material, the emission doesn't work.

Screenshots

[Volume and Mesh renderer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oNFR.png)

[Midway through the prosses of changing colors and emissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zU13V.png)

[Glow material](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwfBc.png)

[Normal material](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9toGm.png)

And here is my code,

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Menu : MonoBehaviour {

    public Material glow_mat;
    public Material normal_mat;
    public float spin_speed;
    public SkinnedMeshRenderer renderer;
    public bool changing;
    public bool glow_change;
    public float change_amount;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void OnEnable() {
        StartCoroutine(changeColorStart());
    }

    IEnumerator changeColorStart() {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(1, 5));
        glow_change = true;
        changing = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        transform.Rotate(0, spin_speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        if (changing) {
            change_amount += Time.deltaTime * 2;//0.2s per 1
            if (change_amount > 1) {
                change_amount = 1;
            }
            renderer.materials[0].Lerp(glow_change ? normal_mat : glow_mat, glow_change ?  glow_mat : normal_mat, change_amount);
            if (change_amount == 1) {
                change_amount = 0;
                if (glow_change) {
                    glow_change = false;
                } else {
                    changing = false;
                    StartCoroutine(changeColorStart());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this to work, if you're wondering you need to put this code after a material change,

```cs
mat.SetColor("_EmissionColor", targetColor);//Or whatever material change you have.
mat.EnableKeyword("_EMISSION");//This is a bug in unity
```

I found the answer on the unity docs, [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/lwrp-not-updating-material-correctly.789605/).